# How to show images in local google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, github

I want to show photos in google maps, my project looks like this:

```
/index.html
/photos/1.jpg
/photos/2.jpg
/photos/.....
```

`index.html` is embedded with a google maps, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

So when I open `index.html` in local browser, a google map would be displayed. Then I want to show `photos/*.jpg` on the map. How can do that?

Is there some libs help me to do that? I searched github but cannot found one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand the question, but if I do, then you need to do this on Google's end. Not yours. What you do, is you go to https://mapsengine.google.com/map/ and set it up how you need to. You can set it up by typing in the address of the location you want (or drop a pin) and then click on that pin. You can then choose to "Add to Map" and it saves that location. Once you have all the locations you want, you can edit them by clicking the little paint bucket icon that appears when you scroll over the locations. Unfortunately, you can only use Your icons in the Pro version which will cost you. If you want, you can then import the map with an iframe by clicking share in the upper right hand side of the screen. Set 'Who has access' to Public, and copy the link. Paste that link into an `<iframe>` and then change the word `edit` to `embed`. Your result should look like this `<iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zT7J1AkkmHFM.kQCUyqfvFqZA"></iframe>` set the iframe to the way you need it to be, and you are good to go.